# React - useState property not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm having trouble with react `useState` hook. I'm trying to clean the state on a dialog close. But theres's always one property that does not gets updated.

Buttons:

```
Create btn
<Button className={classes.dashboardPosts__newPost} onClick={handleClickOpen}>nuevo post</Button>
Edit btn
<TableCell className={classes.dashboardPosts__bodyCell}><CreateIcon onClick={(e) => { onClickEdit(e, post._id) }} /></TableCell>
```

**---- Edit ----**

```
Close btn
<Button className={classes.dashboardPosts__modalButtons} onClick={handleClose} color="primary">Cancelar</Button>
```

That button opens a dialog box which has a textfield:

```
<Button className={classes.dashboardPosts__modalButtons} type="submit" color="primary">{input._id ? "Editar" : "Crear"}</Button>
```

This is how the dialog box open and closes:

```
const handleClickOpen = () => {
  setOpen(true);
};

const handleClose = () => {
  setPreviewLink("")
  setFile("No se ha seleccionado ningún archivo")
  setInput({
      _id: "",
      p_title: "",
      p_body: "",
      p_mainImage: null,
      p_link: ""
  })
  setOpen(false);
};
```

This is the state:

```
const [input, setInput] = useState({
   _id: "",
   p_title: "",
   p_body: "",
   p_mainImage: null,
   p_link: ""
})
```

This is the edit button click:

```
const onClickEdit = (e, id) => {
   e.preventDefault()
   const p = postsList.filter((up) => {
       return up._id === id
   })
   setInput({
       ...input,
       p_body: p[0].p_body,
       p_title: p[0].p_title,
       _id: p[0]._id,
       p_mainImage: p[0].p_mainImage,
   })
   setPreviewLink(p[0].p_title.replace(titleRegex, '').split(" ").join("-").toLowerCase())
   setFile(p[0].p_mainImage.split("").splice(0, 40).join("") + "...")
   handleClickOpen(e)
 }
```

The expected functionality is that when I click the edit btn, the modal opens with the post details and when the modal is closed, clean `input` so whenever I click on new post button the form is clean. However the form only gets clean when I open the modal with the new post button and then close it, not when I open it with the edit button. Everything gets cleaned but the `p_title` property.

**--- Edit ---**

So the problem was in my `input onChange` function, this is it:

```
const onInputChange = (e, name, data = "") => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setInput({ ...input, [name]: data !== "" ? data : e.target.value })
        if (name === "p_title") setPreviewLink(e.target.value.replace(titleRegex, '').split(" ").join("-").toLowerCase())
        if (name === "p_approved") {
            setInput({ ...input, [name]: !input.p_approved })
            return
        }
    }
```

However I don't know how to solve it. My guess is that when the editor (CKeditor) input changes, it sets `p_title` to it's original value.

Comment: Where do you call `handleClose `?

Comment: @HảiBùi I just edited the post. `handleClose` is called when I click the outside of the dialog box or when I press the close button inside it.

Comment: Does `p[0]` have values other than `p_title`? Whatever info you have provided that looks good as per my understanding.

Comment: try to console.log(p) before your setInput in the onClickEdit
have you listed all "setInput" occurencies in the question?

Comment: @sunnyprakash I log `p_title` everytime I make a change but it's always a string

Comment: @2oppin already tried, it logs a object with the properties empty. I missed one, i'll edit the post. I know now where's the error but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: if p[0] is empty in your setInput in the onClickEdit, it means that postLists either have no record with matched "id" or is the array that doesn't contain properties you need.
I suspect that you render your Table with valid collection, why not to pass whole "post"
into onClickEdit instead of just "post._id"?

Comment: I could do that, however I've deleted `setInput({ ...input, [name]: data !== "" ? data : e.target.value })` in `onInputChange` and it works, the only problem is that that function handles the input changes so I can't remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it. What was happening is that whenever I updated the `input` state, the `ckeditor` component detected change so it changed the `input` state to the one that I set before closing the dialog box.

The solution was to create a diferent function to update `ckeditor` state, so the whole state doesn't change when `ckeditor` updates.

This was the new function to update ckeditor state

```
const onEditorChange = (e, editor) => {
    setCkeditor(editor.getData())
}
```